# How to sort NSMutableDictionary with dynamic keys in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutabledictionary

I am getting following dictionary as JSON response

```
Lease =     {
    "KINDERSLEY KERROBERT" =
    (
     {
         "lease_code" = 37;
     },
     {
         "lease_code" = 38;
     }
     );
    LLOYDMINSTER =
    (
     {
         "lease_code" = 68;
     },
     {
         "lease_code" = 69;
     }
     );
    "SOUTHEASTERN SASKATCHEWAN" =
    (
     {
         "lease_code" = 1;
     },
     {
         "lease_code" = 2;
     }
     );
    "SWIFT CURRENT" =
    (
     {
         "lease_code" = 32;
     },
     {
         "lease_code" = 33;
     }
     );
    };
```

I would like to sort it as follow:

```
 Lease =     {
"SOUTHEASTERN SASKATCHEWAN" =
(
 {
     "lease_code" = 1;
 },
 {
     "lease_code" = 2;
 }
 );
"SWIFT CURRENT" =
(
 {
     "lease_code" = 32;
 },
 {
     "lease_code" = 33;
 }
 );
"KINDERSLEY KERROBERT" =
(
 {
     "lease_code" = 37;
 },
 {
     "lease_code" = 38;
 }
 );
LLOYDMINSTER =
(
 {
     "lease_code" = 68;
 },
 {
     "lease_code" = 69;
 }
 );
};
```

I wrote below code to sort dictionary:

```
- (NSArray *)sortKeysByIntValue:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    NSArray *sortedKeys = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSArray *obj1, NSArray *obj2) {
        NSString* key1 = [[obj1 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"lease_code"];
        NSString* key2 = [[obj2 objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"lease_code"];
        return [key1 compare:key2];
    }];
    return sortedKeys;
}
```

It gives me sortedKeys that I want, But after rebuilding `NSMutableDictionary` using below code:

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [self sortKeysByIntValue:dictionary];
NSMutableDictionary *sortedDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

for (NSString *key in sortedKeys) {
    [sortedDictionary setObject:dictionary[key] forKey:key];
}
```

It again unsorted as shown in response.

please help me out

Comment: a dictionary can't be sorted. and you don't need it

Comment: i badly need it to display sorted value in table and a dictionary can be sorted.

Comment: dictionaries cannot be sorted. it is their nature. actually you have already your keys sorted. that's all you need. you could now have for example another array which would keep every value corresponding to a key for every index

Comment: Normally, what you'd do is keep an array of dictionary keys and sort the array using whatever criteria is required from the dictionary.  You can then use this array to drive the order of tableview items, for example.

Comment: you see that using that sorted array i create new dictionary but it doesn't work

Comment: @VirajPadsala it will never work. it is not supposed to. did you read my comment? the one with 4 upvotes. you need to maintain two arrays. does it makes sense?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha what will be inside that array?

Comment: let me cite myself: "another array which would keep every value corresponding to a key for every index". so you have sorted keys. they are sorted just like you need. then what you need is to have the values sorted in the same order. so what you do is you put into another array values from the dictionary. you take the key from the index 0. then you get value for that key. then you put this value into index 0 in the second array. then you proceed with index 1 and so on. is that clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dictionaries are always unsorted. They are used as a key value storage to look up data. You should keep the order of your data separate from the dictionary. You need the dictionary you already have AND a sorted array of the keys.

```
@property NSDictionary *dataDict;
@property NSArray *sortedKeys;

self.sortedKeys = [self sortKeysByIntValue:self.dataDict];
```

In a `UITableViewDataSource` method, you would first consult your array with the index, get the key, and then retrieve the data from the dictionary.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *key = [self.sortedkeys objectAtIndex:row];
    NSObject *dataObject = [self.dataDict valueForKey:key];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *sortedKeys = [self sortKeysByIntValue:dictionary];
NSMutableArray* values = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSString* key in sortedKeys)
{
   [values addObject:dictionary[key]];
}
```

Now you have both your keys and values sorted. This is exactly what you need